# How do we sort the list of javers shadows based on created ts

Tags: javers

I cannot see a feature to add sorting to a JQLQuery. Is there any way to get a sorted list of shadows?

```
javers.findShadows(QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().withCommitProperty(commit_id_property_key, entityId)
                    .skip(offset.orElse(0) * size.orElse(default_shadow_limit))
                    .limit(size.orElse(default_shadow_limit)).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is none according to this - https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/534

"JaVers always sorts by commitId in descending order. This is equiv to sorting by commit date desc. This order (reverse chronological) is fundamental for some javers features (like new Shadows) so we cant change it."